# Чтение файла из архива без распаковки в C#

Tags: c#, wpf, zip, compression

Мне необходимо **читать** текстовый файл, что находится в архиве построчно. Распаковывать его на жесткий диск **нельзя**. Использую библиотеку Ionic.Zip, но буду не против если покажите кусок кода со встроенной библиотекой. Заранее спасибо. Так же для меня будет очень приятным бонусом если кто-нибудь расскажет как получать картинки из архива и без распаковки использовать их в Image (WPF).

Comment: Наверное вам нужно ознакомится с этим - http://ethw.org/History_of_Lossless_Data_Compression_Algorithms зная алгоритмы вы всегда сможете написать свой метод, но это будет всё-равно распаковка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По поводу чтения текста из файла - вот решение:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(e.OpenReader(password), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
{
    sr.Readline();
}
```

Где e - ZipEntry, а password - пароль если есть.
По поводу картинок не понял до сих пор.

Answer (score 0):

Насчет чтения картинки из архива. Используя библиотеку Ionic.Zip:

```
public static MemoryStream GetFileImage(string ZPass, string ZipPath, string ImageName) //получаем картинку из архива по имени
        {
            MemoryStream ImageMS = new MemoryStream();
            using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(ZipPath))
            {
                zip.Password = ZPass;
                try { zip[ImageName].Extract(ImageMS); }
                catch { /*либо файла нет, либо пароль неверный*/ }
            }
            ImageMS.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return ImageMS;
        }
```

Для чтения используйте код:

```
MemoryStream mStream = GetFileImage("Password", "ZipPath", "ImageName")
Image image = Image.FromStream(mStream);
```